# The SearchBox ENTER being enabled on the whole site

Tags: php

I have in my site a searchBox in html and jquery, the problem is that anywhere on my site when I press ENTER I am sent to the searchBox search result page regardless of whether I am typing / selecting it or not

HTML SearchBox code:

```
                        <li>
                        <div class="formBusca">
                            <form role="search" method="post" class="search-form" action="">
                                <div class="input-busca">
                                    <input type="search" class="search-field" id="palavra-chave" placeholder="Busca..." name="palavra-chave" title="Pesquisar">
                                </div>
                                <div class="botao-busca">
                                    <input type="button" class="search-submit" id="busca-site" value="">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
```

jQuery Code:

```
<script >
$( ".divMenuMobile" ).click(function() {
    $(".header .navMobile").slideToggle();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#busca-site").trigger("click");
        }
    });
});

$(function() {

    //REALIZAR BUSCA
    $("#busca-site").click(function(){

        var nome  = $("#palavra-chave").val()  != "" ? $("#palavra-chave").val()  : "indefinido";

        window.location = "<?php echo URL_SITE; ?>/home/pesquisa/"+nome;

    });


});
```

Comment: $(document).keypress() listens to the entire site. Drop in $('#palavra-chave').keypress(...) And itll just listen for the keypresses on that specific element

Comment: Worked, thx bro!!! :D